# fish shell: ctrl-p is not working but ARROW UP is

Tags: fish

I recently installed various fisher plugins and updated to fish 3.4.1 and now "ctrl-p" does not cycle through my commands anymore, but ARROW UP is still working. When I switch to the bash shell, ctrl-p is working. I observe the same behaviour in the gnome terminal and kitty terminal. I have no clue what the problem is and would appreciate a lot if someone could help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears one of your plugins rebound ctrl-p.

In general, to find out what a key sequence is bound to, you need to:

1. Figure out what the key sequence is by starting `fish_key_reader` and pressing it
2. Pass that to `bind`

So, you run `fish_key_reader`, which tells you:

```
bind \cP 'do something'
```

That means ctrl-p sends `\cP`.

So, we ask what `\cP` is bound to:

```
bind \cP
```

which by default gives us

```
bind --preset \cp up-or-search
```

(yes, the case is indeed irrelevant after a `\c` as `\cp` and `\cP` encode the same).

And if you had bound something differently, it might print multiple lines like

```
bind --preset \cp up-or-search
bind \cp 'echo oops'
```

What can also happen here is that one of your plugins enabled vi-mode (this can happen even for things you might think are entirely unrelated, for instance there's at least [one semi-popular prompt](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/theme-budspencer) that believes it's entitled to enable it).

In that case, `bind \cP` will output nothing, and you can also ask `bind -M insert \cP` to ask what ctrl-p is bound to in insert mode.

To disable vi-mode and go back to the default emacs-inspired bindings (where that binding for ctrl-p originated), run `fish_default_key_bindings`.

Comment: Thanks! I enabled vi-mode myself and I did not understand that I have to run `fish_default_key_bindings` again (I only removed `fish_vi_key_bindings` from the config.fish)

Comment: By default, fish will show a mode-indicator when you're running in vi-mode. That's a green `[I]` or red `[N]` in front of the prompt. Most likely your prompt disables it again - which removes valuable information.

Comment: Also: Most fish questions are probably better suited for unix.stackexchange.com - there are some users here who like to close all questions that aren't strictly about programming, and when it's about fish the boundary is sometimes unclear.